# How to install Nokogiri on Ruby 2.7.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I recently upgraded to Ruby v2.7.0.

When I tried to install Nokogiri I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        The last version of nokogiri (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was
1.10.9. Try installing it with `gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.9`
        nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3, < 2.7.dev. The current ruby versi
on is 2.7.0.0.
```

I tried to install this gem with

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.9
```

but I got the same error.

How can I install Nokogiri now that I am using Ruby v2.7.0? Do I need to install an earlier version of Ruby?

The results of gem env are:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.0 (2019-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x64-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/gritz/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd/git.EXE
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby27-x64/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/gritz/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x64-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - C:/Users/gritz/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\windows\system32
     - C:\windows
     - C:\windows\System32\Wbem
     - C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
     - C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\
     - C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
     - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
     - C:\Program Files\erl10.3\bin
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Elixir\bin
     - C:\Users\gritz\.mix\escripts
     - C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
     - C:\Users\gritz\.rbenv-win\bin
     - C:\Users\gritz\.rbenv-win\shims
     - C:\Users\gritz\.rbenv-win\bin
     - C:\Users\gritz\.rbenv-win\shims
     - C:\Users\gritz\.rbenv-win\bin
     - C:\Users\gritz\.rbenv-win\shims
     - _SZ    C:\Ruby26\bin
     - C:\Ruby27-x64\bin
     - C:\Ruby26-x64\bin
     - %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

In response to one of the comments, I am adding the results of gem specification -r nokogiri:

```
-r nokogiri
--- !ruby/object:Gem::Specification
name: nokogiri
version: !ruby/object:Gem::Version
  version: 1.10.9
platform: ruby
authors:
- Aaron Patterson
- Mike Dalessio
- Yoko Harada
- Tim Elliott
- Akinori MUSHA
- John Shahid
- Lars Kanis
autorequire:
bindir: bin
cert_chain: []
date: 2020-03-01 00:00:00.000000000 Z
dependencies:
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: mini_portile2
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 2.4.0
  type: :runtime
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 2.4.0
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: concourse
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '0.24'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '0.24'
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: hoe-bundler
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '1.2'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '1.2'
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: hoe-debugging
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '2.0'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '2.0'
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: hoe-gemspec
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '1.0'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '1.0'
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: hoe-git
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '1.6'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '1.6'
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: minitest
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '5.8'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '5.8'
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: racc
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 1.4.14
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 1.4.14
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: rake
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '12.0'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '12.0'
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: rake-compiler
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 1.1.0
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 1.1.0
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: rake-compiler-dock
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 0.7.0
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 0.7.0
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: rexical
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 1.0.5
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: 1.0.5
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: rubocop
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '0.73'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '0.73'
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: simplecov
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '0.16'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '0.16'
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: rdoc
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '4.0'
    - - "<"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '7'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '4.0'
    - - "<"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '7'
- !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
  name: hoe
  requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '3.22'
  type: :development
  prerelease: false
  version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
    requirements:
    - - "~>"
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
        version: '3.22'
description: |-
  Nokogiri (?) is an HTML, XML, SAX, and Reader parser.  Among
  Nokogiri's many features is the ability to search documents via XPath
  or CSS3 selectors.
email:
- aaronp@rubyforge.org
- mike.dalessio@gmail.com
- yokolet@gmail.com
- tle@holymonkey.com
- knu@idaemons.org
- jvshahid@gmail.com
- lars@greiz-reinsdorf.de
executables: []
extensions: []
extra_rdoc_files: []
files: []
homepage: https://nokogiri.org
licenses: []
metadata:
  homepage_uri: https://nokogiri.org
  bug_tracker_uri: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues
  documentation_uri: https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/index.html
  changelog_uri: https://nokogiri.org/CHANGELOG.html
  source_code_uri: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri
post_install_message:
rdoc_options: []
require_paths:
- lib
required_ruby_version: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
  requirements:
  - - ">="
    - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
      version: 2.3.0
required_rubygems_version: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
  requirements:
  - - ">="
    - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
      version: '0'
requirements: []
rubygems_version: 3.1.2
signing_key:
specification_version: 4
summary: Nokogiri (?) is an HTML, XML, SAX, and Reader parser
test_files: []
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce with `ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin19]`. `gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.9` completes successfully. Please provide more information on your environment and versions, the exact commands entered, and the exact output received.

Comment: "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" along with "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" are important reading. We can't duplicate the problem, and without being able to the question will be off-topic. Add the output of `gem env` to your question, formatted correctly and without "edit" or "update" type tags.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Ruby installed? Are you using a sandbox like rbenv or RVM?

Comment: I do have multiple versions of Ruby installed. I am not using a version manager like rvm.

Comment: This is the perfectly valid question, I couldn't install nokogiri gem in ruby 2.7. I have been facing this problem for weeks now. The same error which he has shown is getting displayed.

Comment: @Rajagopalan: It is a valid question. But now it's also a _good_ question, now that OP has edited in their environment. anothermh seemed to answer from the OSX perspective, so maybe this is something that only happens on Windows? Tagging with [tag:windows] might be warranted. Adding `gem specification -r nokogiri` might also be good.

Comment: @Amadan Okay,that makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Ruby + DevKit, try this command:

```
gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby
```

It should install nokogiri and make it fit with your version of Ruby.
In case if it fails again or takes forever to fetch and install gem, run this command first:

```
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libxslt
```

Then this one:

```
gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby -- --use-system-libraries
```

Nokogori should be installed after these commands.